# edit listview row items or adding to it

Tags: c#

Im trying to edit a listview row's items names.

This is the function i use to add the items to list view

```
    public static void AddRow(this ListView lvw, int image_index,
        string item_title, params string[] subitem_titles)
    {
        // Make the item.
        ListViewItem new_item = lvw.Items.Add(item_title, 1);

        // Set the item's image index.
        new_item.ImageIndex = image_index;
        // Make the sub-items.
        for (int i = subitem_titles.GetLowerBound(0);
                 i <= subitem_titles.GetUpperBound(0);
                 i++)
        {
            new_item.SubItems.Add(subitem_titles[i]);
        }
    }
```

This is what i have tried so far, Trying to edit the text or even add new items

```
public static void EditRow(this ListView lvw, int image_index,
    string item_title, params string[] subitem_titles)
{
    //ListViewItem lvi = lvw.Items[image_index];

    for (int i = 0; i < lvw.Items[image_index].SubItems.Count; i++)
    {
        lvw.Items[image_index].SubItems[i].Text = subitem_titles[i];
    }
}
```

.

Update:

Think i have worked it out

```
public static void EditRow(this ListView lvw, int image_index,
    string item_title, params string[] subitem_titles)
{
    if (lvw.InvokeRequired)
        lvw.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            for (int i = subitem_titles.GetLowerBound(0); i <= subitem_titles.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
                lvw.Items[image_index].SubItems[i + 1].Text = subitem_titles[i];
        }));
    else
    {
        for (int i = subitem_titles.GetLowerBound(0);i <= subitem_titles.GetUpperBound(0);i++)
            lvw.Items[image_index].SubItems[i + 1].Text = subitem_titles[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "row item names"?

Comment: The subitems, but for some reason `lvw.Items[image_index].SubItems.Count` is empty

Comment: Why are you using `image_index` to select the row in `EditRow`?

Comment: just named wrong that is the index of the item

Comment: Maybe you are passing the wrong index? Your question does not contain enough code to allow us to see the problem

Comment: I think its to do with me running it in a backgrounfWorker, and it cant access the listview right way.